# Video on Firefox Mac extremely sluggish

Tags: macos, firefox, video, html5-video

Even within the simplest html file, a video file is played extremely sluggished (about 8fps) in Firefox Mac.  Other browsers/OS work fine.  When i use the url of the video directly in the browser, no problem.  I happens only when inserted into a html, using a standard html5-video.

Example of video url :
http://maxxhat.com/wp-backend/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/showreel-short.mp4.mp4

Using latest versions of MacOS High Sierra (Version 10.13.6) — Firefox Quantum 61.0.2 (64-bit)

Any idea ?

Thank you!

Comment: Plays smoothly when I test - can you share your OSX and Firefox versions?

Comment: @Mick OSX and Firefox are the latest.  Keep in mind it plays well when inserted in url, only sluggish within html5 video...  Can you confirmed you tested it that way?    On PC i get around 54fps, not more than 8fps on mac.

Comment: @Mick macOS High Sierra (Version 10.13.6) — Firefox Quantum 61.0.2 (64-bit)

Comment: The following worked in a JSFiddle on Firefox, smoothly: <video width="320" height="240" controls autoplay>
  <source src="http://maxxhat.com/wp-backend/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/showreel-short.mp4.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

Comment: @Mick Found the issues... Thanx for the input !  Best regards from Belgium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i got it :

I had two attributes that were slowing it down drastically:

`style="filter:brightness(108%);"` (used to correct some rgb range interpretation) and... `muted` !

Beware that removing the `muted` blocks the video on Chrome.  So i ended up building an exception on Firefox to remove the attribute `muted`.